# print array with proper indentation

Tags: php, arrays, json, pretty-print

```
foreach ( $custom_fields as $field_key => $field_values ) {
    foreach ( $field_values as $key => $value )
        echo $field_key . '<br>';
        echo '<pre>' , print_r( $value,true) , '</pre>';
}
```

Although I'm using `print_r` with `<pre>` tag, the ouput looks like this:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:6:"Casual";i:1;s:6:"Serene";i:2;s:6:"Unique";i:3;s:9:"Whimsical";}
```

shouldn't it be listed vertically with proper indentation? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use nl2br(print_r($custom_fields, TRUE));

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a serialized array, use `unserialize()` to turn it back to an array again:

```
foreach ( $custom_fields as $field_key => $field_values ) {
    foreach ( $field_values as $key => $value ) {
        $value = unserialize($value);
        echo $field_key . '<br/>';
        echo '<pre>' , print_r($value, true) , '</pre>';
    } 
}
```

What it would look like:

http://codepad.viper-7.com/5Rppb3

Comment: Put the <pre> in foreach like in @Nimbuz example

Comment: @Nimbuz, Yes, take a look to `serialize/unserialize` on `php.net`

Answer (score 0):

you can use only

```
    $value=unserialize($custom_fields); 
    echo '<pre>' ;    
    var_dump($value);
    echo '</pre>';
```